# Redirect the Email Address Link to their Specific Domain Names

Tags: email

I have a question, please anyone out there help me!!

i have an email address like `"user@example.com"` when i click this email address, it should go to their specific domain name i.e, `www.example.com,`

same like that if there an email id like `"user@gmail.com"`, this should be automatically go to the `www.gmail.com` when clicking this email address!!

simply that have to redirect to the domain name after the @ symbol?

So, my actual final url will be like this when clicking the above email id links  `"www.mysite.com/user@example.com"`
Please prefer a Url rewrite code for this to be added in .htaccess file!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the reply bro., i want url rewrite code for .htaccess file.

Comment: Are you doing this in php, if so, you don't need to use htaccess.

Comment: i wanna use this in magento bro., So, my actual final url will be like this when clicking the abouve email id links "www.mysite.com/user@example.com"